# Quadratic equations and probability

Tags: quadratics

The inequality:

4p^2-17p+4>0

Solving using quadratic equation:

(−(−17)±√(−17)^2−4⋅4⋅4)/8
=(12±√225)/8

I realize why p = 4 or p = 1/4, and in this case p represents and probability so the solution is 1/4 but how do I know if p is < or > than 1/4.

Thanks.

Comment: Draw a graph of $y=4p^2-17p+4$.  For which values of $p$ is $y>0$?

Answer (score 2):

$4p^2 - 17p + 4 = (4p - 1)(p - 4) > 0$.

You already know that $0 \le p \le 1$ since it is a probability, so that means $p < 4$. So $p - 4 < 0$. This means: $4p - 1 < 0$, and so $p < \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

4p^2 - 17p +4 >0
First solve for the critical values 
4p^2 -17p + 4 = 0
p= 4, p= 1/4

Draw a number line , and mark 4 and 1/4 , if it is a function greater than 0 which is in this case, draw an arrow from 4 away from 1/4 which is p> 4 , and same for 1/4 u draw a line away from 4 which is p < 1/4. So the solution is p>4 , p<1/4.

Now imagine if it was 
4p^2 - 17p + 4<0 
Less than zero ^^^ then you draw a arrow inwards from 1/4 towards 4 and same thing for 4 u draw towards 1/4 , which gives the solution region as 1/4

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square gives:

$(2p-\frac{17}{4})^{2}>(\frac{17}{4})^{2}-4$

Taking the square root of both sides gives:

$$|2p-\frac{17}{4}|>\frac{15}{4}
\\\iff
2p-\frac{17}{4}>\frac{15}{4}
\text{ or }  
2p-\frac{17}{4}<-\frac{15}{4}\\
\iff
p>4\text{ or } p<\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: For all the students reading this - the quadratic formula doesn't solve every problem involving quadratics!!! Learn to complete the square!!! :)

Comment: How do I complete the square when the second degree coefficient is greater than one i.e. I can do it when x^2+4x-4, for example, but I can't work out how to do when 3x^2+4x-4

Comment: 3x^2+4x-4=3(x^2+4x/3)-4=3(x^2+4x/3+4/9-4/9)-4=3((x+2/3)^2-4/9)-4=3(x+2/3)^2-16/3

Answer (score 0):

$$4p^2-17p+4=(4p-1)(p-4)>0$$
$$\iff(4p-1>0\&p-4>0)\text{or}(4p-1<0\&p-4<0)$$
$$\iff(p>1/4\&p>4)\text{or}(p<1/4\&p<4)$$
$$\iff(p>4)\text{or}(p<1/4)$$
$$\iff p\in(-\infty,1/4)\cup(4,\infty)$$
since $p$ is probability $0\leq p\leq1$ after combining these results finally $0\leq p<1/4$

Comment: I understand that dividing either (4p−1) or (p−4)results in (4p−1>0) & (p−4>0) but not (4p−1<0) & (p−4<0)

Comment: because $(-a)\cdot(-b)=+(a\cdot b)$